# Stack implemented with a linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, stack

I have made a basic stack class utilizing a linked list for data storage and \$O(1)\$ push and pop and just want some basic feedback on the class to see if there is anything basic I missed. It seems to be working perfectly and I know there are no memory leaks. I'm just being cautious and wondering if there is one or two big things I am missing or doing wrong.

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
public:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    Node(T data) : data(data) {}
    Node(T data, Node *next) : data(data), next(next) {}
  };
  Node *top;
  int size_;

  Stack() : size_(0), top(nullptr) {}

  bool empty() {
    return top == 0;
  }

  void push(T data) {
    if(empty()) {
      top = new Node(data);
      size_++;
    } else {
      top = new Node(data, top);
      size_++;
    }
  }

  T pop() {
    if(!empty()) {
      T ret = top->data;
      Node *tmp = top->next;
      delete top;
      top = tmp;
      size_--;
      return ret;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  int size() {
    return size_;
  }

  ~Stack() {
    if(empty()) return;

    if(size_ == 1) {
      delete top;
      return;
    }

    Node *current = top;
    Node *next;
    while( current != 0 ) {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    top = nullptr;

  }

};
```

Comment: Take a look into [const methods](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns). `empty()` and `size()` should be `const`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is easy to read, formatting is pretty consistent, and does indeed do what it is supposed to as far as I can tell, so that's a good. I just have a few suggestions.

```
class Stack {
public:
```

Well if everything is `public`, use a `struct` instead, it will save you a few keystrokes. But the `size_` and `top` members probably shouldn't be public - they're not meant to be inspected (much less changed) from outside your class.

```
bool empty() { return top == 0; }
while (current != 0) {
```

Prefer `nullptr` instead of `0` (you already did that in other places).

```
void push(T data) {
  if(empty()) {
    top = new Node(data);
    size_++;
  } else {
    top = new Node(data, top);
    size_++;
  }
}
```

You can simplify this: if the stack is empty, then `top` is null, and `new Node(data)` does the same thing as `new Node(data, nullptr)`. So you don't need the conditional, you can simplify it to:

```
void push(T data) {
  top = new Node(data, top);
  size_++;
}
```

The `pop` function will fail to compile for e.g. `Stack<std::string>`: you can't construct a string from `-1`. Your only real option here is to throw an exception if `pop` is called on an empty stack. (You should look at the standard container's interface: they have separate `top()` and `pop()` members. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616793/635608) for example as for why it is done that way.)

And your destructor is a bit too complex, you don't need the two special cases as they'll be handled by the main loop just fine: if `empty()`, `top` is null so the while loop simply won't run. If there's just one element, the while loop will run just once. So you can cut it down to:

```
~Stack()
{ 
  while (top != nullptr) {
    Node *next = top->next;
    delete top;
    top = next;
  }
}
```

One last observation - what happens if someone writes this:

```
Stack<int> s1;
s1.push(1);
Stack<int> s2 = s1;
s1.pop();
s2.pop();
```

Unfortunately, this will compile but produces undefined behavior - the second pop will access free'd memory. You should either implement the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (sometimes now called the "rule of 5" taking into account move constructor and move assignment), or simply not allow copying of your stacks:

```
Stack(Stack const&) = delete;
```